# Why is winhex not retrieving files

Tags: android, gdb, gdbserver, .net-reflector

I am doing some reverse engineering to get the .dll of a game.

I have tried following the instruction to decrypt the `assembly-Csharp.dll` using `gcore` but when I try to open the file and recover it on `winhex` it says

```
"9 file headers were found but 0 files were retrieved"
```

Is there any useful software you guys know?